# grouping xtics with strings

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to group some tics in gnuplot. For example, the x-axis should look like

```
|  program 1 | program 2 | program 3 | program 4 |
|          group 1       |       group 2         |
```

How it is possible?

UPDATE:

According to [examples](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/histograms2.html), I have one data file contains

```
10
20
30
40
```

So I wrote

```
set xtics ("program 1" 0, "program 2" 1, "program 3" 2, "program 4" 3)
plot \
newhistogram "group 1", "data.txt" every ::1::2 with boxes, \
newhistogram "group 2", "data.txt" every ::3::4 with boxes
```

But the plot doesn't contain program 3 and 4

Comment: You can manually place some of the labels. If you also want all those lines as tics? How you can do this depends on the flexability, where those label information comes from (data file?), etc. Maybe you can be a bit more precise, because it is not possible out-of-the-box, unless you are dealing with histograms, see [histogram2.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/histograms2.html).

Comment: OK I understand it, but can not reproduce it. Please see the updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you must change your script:

1. Use the `histogram` plotting style.
2. Use a `rowstacked` histogram.
3. `every` starts at `0`

   ```
   set offset 0,0,1,0
   set style data histogram
   set style histogram rowstacked title offset 0,-1
   set bmargin 4
   set xtics ("program 1" 0, "program 2" 1, "program 3" 3, "program 4" 4)
   plot newhistogram " \n group 1" , "data.txt" every ::0::1, \
        newhistogram "group 2", "data.txt" every ::2::3
   ```

This leaves by default a gap of `1` between the two `histograms`. If you want them to be placed side by side, you can place the second one with `at 2`. In this case you would need to adjust the `xtics` back to what you had.

This gives (with 4.6.4):

[image]

If you want to have the tics placed between the boxes, you must add them manually. There is no such option to have the tics between the labels:

1. Set the scale of the major tics to `0`, and that of the minor tics to the original scale of the major tics: `set xtics scale 0,1`
2. Add one minor tic between two major tics. Using `set mxtics 2` doesn't work, because thats only for automatic xtics. To add minor tics, use `set xtics add` and specify `1` as level to get minor tics: `set xtics add (-0.5 1)`. You need to add all tics manually, but with 4.6.x you can iterate that: `set for [i=-1:4] xtics add (i+0.5 i)`.

With these changes (and using `set boxwidth 0.8` and some other settings), the result is the following (with 4.6.4):

[image]

Comment: @mahmood I saw you other question (which was deleted) about setting the tics between the labels, and was preparing an answer. I supposed it was meant for this use case, so I appended it here.