# How can I pair and rename x-axis double rename 2 by 1 in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add hours and group within itself by date. It is, but want to show on *x-axis*. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429008/grouping-xtics-with-strings) but couldn't use properly. Getting following error.

```
"gnuplot.gnu" line 16: undefined variable: rowstacked
```

*Edit*:I have to show data whether intersect each other. Each individual draws line is independent in my scenario. So I've to stick to individual indicator lines. I have to use times and dates over x-axis in line plot mode below.

```java
### plot easy!
reset session
set key left box
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb"#ffffff" behind
set datafile separator tab

set grid x y my
set xlabel "Setted"
set ylabel "Getted "
set title "Sensor Datas"
set style lines rowstacked title offset 0,-1

set autoscale

#set xtics ("12:00 PM" 0, "6:00 PM" 1, "12:00 PM" 2, "6:00 PM" 4,"12:00 PM" 5, "6:00 PM" 6 )
#plot newlines" \n group 1" , "./Sensor Datas.txt" every ::0::1, \
#     newlines "group 2", "./Sensor Datas.txt" every ::2::3


plot "./Sensor Datas.txt" u 2 t "a"    w l,\
     "./Sensor Datas.txt" u 3 t "b"    w l,\
     "./Sensor Datas.txt" u 4 t "c"    w l,\
     "./Sensor Datas.txt" u 5 t "d"    w l,\
     "./Sensor Datas.txt" u 6 t "e"    w l,\
     "./Sensor Datas.txt" u 7 t "f"    w l,
```

| x |  | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/24/2022 | 12:00 PM | 68.60 | 64.30 | 61.60 | 54.70 | 91.40 | 148.00 |
|  | 6:00 PM | 67.08 | 55.26 | 66.50 | 54.05 | 91.20 | 152.00 |
| 9/25/2022 | 12:00 PM | 70.10 | 71.60 | 64.40 | 59.00 | 85.60 | 154.00 |
|  | 6:00 PM | 74.40 | 80.40 | 67.60 | 58.80 | 96.90 | 156.30 |
| 9/26/2022 | 12:00 PM | 66.20 | 90.60 | 65.70 | 55.60 | 67.90 | 156.00 |
|  | 6:00 PM | 78.80 | 107.80 | 66.20 | 56.10 | 58.50 | 153.60 |

[image]

Comment: Which version of gnuplot do you use? I haven't heard about `style lines rowstacked`. Do you want to plot lines or actually a bar chart like in the question you linked?

Comment: I've `gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 5`. I just tried `style lines rowstacked` whether work or not because just only one appeared in my search. Likewise, I'm interested in plot lines for this context.

Comment: So, now no rowstacked line graph? Just simple lines? Do I need to adapt my answer or will you figure it out yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have basically two questions:

1. how to plot a rowstacked line graph? As far as I know there is no dedicated gnuplot plotting style like for histograms. You have to add the values yourself. Check `help sum`. There is an earlier [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40487935/7295599) using a recursive function (however, which will be limited to about 250 instances, although enough for most cases).
2. how to use date/time info from two columns?

Your datafile separator is `tab`, however, I'm not sure if it is possible to post `tab` separated code here on SO. Anyway, that's why I've changed it here to `comma`, but you can easily change it back to `tab` for your original data.
Furthermore, you are using this very unfortunate 12 h (am/pm) time format. A far as I know, gnuplot can read it as ***input*** only from gnuplot 5.4.0 on. For earlier versions you have to use a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59552645/7295599).

Since you skip the date every second row, you have to memorize it in `d0` to plot the values at the right x-(time) position. Furthermore, you create the xticlabel yourself, by a function.

If you don't need the data points as point, simply skip the second part of the plot command.
Check the example below as starting point for further optimization.

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.4.0, because of `%p` as time input format)

```
### rowstacked lineplot with time axis
reset session

$Data <<EOD
         ,         ,     a,      b,     c,     d,     e,      f
9/24/2022, 12:00 PM, 68.60,  64.30, 61.60, 54.70, 91.40, 148.00
         ,  6:00 PM, 67.08,  55.26, 66.50, 54.05, 91.20, 152.00
9/25/2022, 12:00 PM, 70.10,  71.60, 64.40, 59.00, 85.60, 154.00
         ,  6:00 PM, 74.40,  80.40, 67.60, 58.80, 96.90, 156.30
9/26/2022, 12:00 PM, 66.20,  90.60, 65.70, 55.60, 67.90, 156.00
         ,  6:00 PM, 78.80, 107.80, 66.20, 56.10, 58.50, 153.60
EOD

N  = 8
myDateFmt = "%m/%d/%Y"
myTimeFmt = "%H:%M %p"

set key out box width 1 noautotitle
set datafile separator comma
set grid x y my front
set style fill solid 0.7 border
set tics out
set format x "\n" timedate

myDate(col)       = valid(col) ? d0=timecolumn(col,myDateFmt) : d0
myTime(col)       = timecolumn(col,myTimeFmt)
mySecs(col1,col2) = myDate(col1) + myTime(col2)
mySum(n)          = sum [_i=3:n] column(_i)
myTic(col1,col2)  = strftime("%l %p",strptime(myTimeFmt,strcol(col2)))."\n".strcol(col1)

plot for [col=3:N] $Data u (mySecs(1,2)):(mySum(col)):(mySum(col-1)):xtic(myTic(1,2)) \
         w filledcurves ti columnhead(col), \
     for [col=3:N] $Data u (mySecs(1,2)):(mySum(col)):(mySum(col-1)) skip 1 w lp pt 7 lc col-2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (line plot without summation)

**Script:**

In your original script, you were actually plotting column 2, which is the time `12:00 pm` and `6:00 pm` and missing the 8th column. It seems like your your date and time actually is separated by `tab` as well, as shown in your table.

```
### lineplot with time axis
reset session

$Data <<EOD
         ,         ,     a,      b,     c,     d,     e,      f
9/24/2022, 12:00 PM, 68.60,  64.30, 61.60, 54.70, 91.40, 148.00
         ,  6:00 PM, 67.08,  55.26, 66.50, 54.05, 91.20, 152.00
9/25/2022, 12:00 PM, 70.10,  71.60, 64.40, 59.00, 85.60, 154.00
         ,  6:00 PM, 74.40,  80.40, 67.60, 58.80, 96.90, 156.30
9/26/2022, 12:00 PM, 66.20,  90.60, 65.70, 55.60, 67.90, 156.00
         ,  6:00 PM, 78.80, 107.80, 66.20, 56.10, 58.50, 153.60
EOD

N  = 8
myDateFmt = "%m/%d/%Y"
myTimeFmt = "%H:%M %p"

set key out box width 1 noautotitle
set datafile separator comma
set grid x y my front
set style fill solid 0.7 border
set tics out
set format x "\n" timedate
set yrange [0:]

myDate(col)       = valid(col) ? d0=timecolumn(col,myDateFmt) : d0
myTime(col)       = timecolumn(col,myTimeFmt)
mySecs(col1,col2) = myDate(col1) + myTime(col2)
mySum(n)          = sum [_i=3:n] column(_i)
myTic(col1,col2)  = strftime("%l %p",strptime(myTimeFmt,strcol(col2)))."\n".strcol(col1)

plot for [col=3:N] $Data u (mySecs(1,2)):col:xtic(myTic(1,2)) w lp pt 7 lc col-2 ti columnhead(col)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I want to remove `sum` because of no need (added an edit to question) but run across plotting problem. How can I iterate `sum` without summation in case we need this iteration. It uses sum result somehow.

Comment: @maxemilian "How can I iterate sum without summation"...? I don't understand. If you just want lines, plot only the column, i.e. use: `plot for [col=3:N] $Data u (mySecs(1,2)):col:xtic(myTic(1,2)) w lp pt 7 lc col-2 ti columnhead(col)`

Comment: I mean `mySum(n)  = sum [_i=3:n]  column(_i)` column iterates and sum adding up them. Btw it works thx